# Python remove dictionaries from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Python listed dictionaries:

```
_list_ = [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}]

example_search_str1 = 'e1' # for value1 of key1

example_search_str2 = 'e3' # for value3 of key1
```

I want to delete listed dictionaries containing multiple example search strings. How to achieve this? Existing answers didn't help much. Python newbie here.

Comment: Can you post your code where your problem is stemming from?

Comment: You ought to choose another name for your list variable, because `list` is a built-in function/class: it's better not to redefine it.

Comment: Indeed typo, I know list shadows built in name. Editing now.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I'm still not sure what exactly you want to do. What is the expected output, and have you tried?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your doubt ?

Comment: This can be done, of course, but if you need to do this, there is a good chance that you should consider changing your data structure. What kind of data are you holding there?

Comment: I am building a Kodi addon (python 2.7). "Add directory items" function requires listed dictionaries and I want to remove adult items/elements from that list with search strings. Sure I can remove list elements but the list is dynamic and its changing all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but as I understand it, you want to remove dictionaries from a list if their 'key1' value is one of some number of strings.

```
bad_strings = ['e1', 'e3']
new_list = [d for d in old_list if d['key1'] not in bad_strings]
```

EDIT:

Oh, I get it.  I was close.  You want to see if 'key1' value contains the forbidden strings.  also doable.

```
new_list = [d for d in old_list if not any(bad in d['key1'] for bad in bad_strings)]
```

Comment: Exactly. So I have to work with a new list? Isn't it possible to retrieve indices and use del method instead?

Comment: In the OP's example, `value1` is a variable, not a string, though I suspect that's a typo...

Comment: You can get weird behavior when you modify an iterable while iterating over it.  Best not to.

Comment: @brianpck consider these variables strings, it doesn't matter. Question is the same.

Comment: This doesn't do anything. If you set `old_list` to the OP's, your `new_list` var is the exact same because none of the values are *in* 'e1' or 'e2'

Comment: Are you testing before posting? Your new edit returns an empty list `[]`

Comment: @brianpck yeah, because both dictionaries in the example don't pass the criteria.  They both have key1 values that contain substrings we don't want

Comment: @Patrick Haugh: EDIT worked for me. I am going to use if statement when required to use new list. Thank you. I wonder who voted negative. Correct me if I 'm wrong but why someone voted negatively. Why does SOF looks somehow hostile to newbies?

Answer (score 0):

Also for matching (key, unwanted_value) I would maybe try smthng like:

```
list_of_dicts =  [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}]
bad_keys_vals = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')]


def filter_dict_list(list_of_dicts, bad_keys_vals):
    return list(filter(lambda d: any((d[key] != bad_val for key, bad_val in bad_keys_vals)), list_of_dicts))

print(filter_dict_list(list_of_dicts, bad_keys_vals))
>> [{'key2': 'value4', 'key1': 'value3'}]
```

But yes, this result in creating a new list, so you would probably need to overwright the old one.